# Can't load html: [Refused to connect because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src 'self']

Tags: python, html, frontend, hue, jquery-2.0

I am working on setting a plugin for hue and I am having trouble loading a modal, all I have is the next log "Refused to connect to 'http://hue.com/api/some_modal' because it violated the following Content Security Policy directive: connect-src 'self' ". Debugging in Network on developer console I could see that it is canceled and only mentions a jquery component:[|(Status: cancelled)| Type: xhr | Initiator: jquery-2.1.1.min.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCawk.png)

I cannot understand the problem since it only has to load a simple html, I already changed the parameter in the configuration file hue.ini in the line secure_content_security_policy="" as it says on the site:
https://gethue.com/hue-security-improvements/

I hope someone can guide me a bit, thank you very much

Comment: Try here:  https://discourse.gethue.com.   Be patient for a response, romain will respond when able.

Comment: Ok, Thank you so much!